# Difference between fs.open 'rs' flag and fs.openSync

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

I was confused with this, that I found on the [document](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback) in the nodejs.org.

It says that the `rs` flag in `fs.open()` is use to *Open file for reading in synchronous mode*.

It just makes me think this is a *asynchronous file open* but it's doing a *synchronous read*? I was really confused with this point.

After that it noted that this *doesn't turn `fs.open()` into a synchronous blocking call*. If that's what you want then you should be using `fs.openSync()`.

What is the difference between `fs.open`'s `rs` and `fs.openSync`'s `r`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that one function expects a callback. The callback is passed to a low-level binding, so the function will be asynchronous regardless of the flags that you pass to it, hence the reason for the documentation to state that the flag "doesn't turn `fs.open()` into a synchronous blocking call". Take this example:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file = './file';

// fd will always be defined
var fd = fs.openSync(file, 'r');

// fd is undefined because the function returns a
// binding, and the actually fs is passed in a callback
var fd = fs.open(file, 'rs');
```

Event if we don't pass a callback to the asynchronous function, the method isn't structured to return the resultant file descriptor. This is what the sources of the two functions look like:

```
fs.open = function(path, flags, mode, callback) {
  callback = makeCallback(arguments[arguments.length - 1]);
  mode = modeNum(mode, 438 /*=0666*/);

  if (!nullCheck(path, callback)) return;
  binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode, callback);
};

fs.openSync = function(path, flags, mode) {
  mode = modeNum(mode, 438 /*=0666*/);
  nullCheck(path);
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
};
```

Comment: thx, I got it, but I'm still confused with the `'rs'` flag in `fs.open` is `Open file for reading in synchronous mode`. Cause it make me think this is a `Asynchronous file open` but it's doing a `Synchronous reading`? I was really confused with this point.

Comment: The `rs` flag tells the operating system to open the file synchronously, but the function operates with a callback, so it's still an asynchronous function.

Comment: @hexacyanide what would a use case be for using the `rs` flag in `fs.open`?

Comment: @RyderBrooks it can be useful when you want to ensure read/write operations make it directly to the filesystem before returning, and are not cached or queued for completion. For example, this can be useful when you are writing to a shared network file system and need consistency for other readers/writers of the filesystem. On Linux, this sets the `O_SYNC` option, so you can read more about it in the manual for `open(2)`.